# SDL movement stops

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm building a spaceshooter in SDL and C++, the movement is working so far.
The problem is that if I press, lets say UP and I add the RIGHT key (now I'm pressing UP and RIGHT at the same time) the ship stays still for a short time.

Same happens when its moving UP + RIGHT, if I let go the second pressed key, movement stops and I have to start by pressing keys down again.

I guess its some problem with holding and adding keypresses. It would be nice if someone could tell me where to look at.

I'm using SDL2.

```
Uint8 const *keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
while(exit == false) {
    if( SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0 ) {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            exit = true;
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] ) {
            ship.move(-2, 0);
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] ) {
            ship.move(2, 0);
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] ) {
            ship.move(0, -2);
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] ) {
            ship.move(0, 2);
        }
        if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE]) {
            ship.shoot();
        }
    }
    SDL_BlitSurface(ship.getSurface(), NULL, surface, ship.getRect());
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
    SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, 0);
}
```

It was not fixed by something like that:

```
if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] && keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT) {
        ship.move(2, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SDL_PollEvent` is triggered when key state changes, and I believe if you press and hold the key you get the events according to key repeat rate. You should move the keyboard checking code outside `if( SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0 )`:

```
while(exit == false) {
    if( SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0 ) {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            exit = true;
        }
    }

    // you may need to take into account elapsed time to achieve constant speed
    // regardless of frame rate
    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] ) {
        ship.move(-2, 0);
    }
    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] ) {
        ship.move(2, 0);
    }
    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] ) {
        ship.move(0, -2);
    }
    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] ) {
        ship.move(0, 2);
    }
    if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE]) {
        ship.shoot();
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface(ship.getSurface(), NULL, surface, ship.getRect());
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
    SDL_FillRect(surface, NULL, 0);
}
```

Read also [the doc](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideinputkeyboard.html), the code as yours is explicitly named wrong there, and example of correct code is provided.